# How i can find the hierarchy in xctest for a label or static text?

Tags: swift, text, label, xctest

Hi I need to test the static txt present in the window, to see whether a text present or not i used the below code,

```
 XCTAssert(mailwindow.staticTexts["Sign In to access Accounts"].exists)
```

now i need to test the hierarchy of the text.

Example the Sign in to access account should appear after *"hello world"* text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to test positioning rather than hierarchy. XCTest UI testing is geared more towards functional testing rather than for checking layout.

Hierarchically, you could check that a parent view contains both text elements, but this wouldn't assert the order they appear on the screen.

It's possible to assert based on the position of the frame of each element, but if you change the layout of the screen, you may have to rewrite the test.

```
let firstText = app.staticTexts["accessAccountsLabel"]
let secondText = app.staticTexts["helloWorldLabel"]
XCTAssert(firstText.frame.origin.x < secondText.frame.origin.x)
XCTAssert(firstText.frame.origin.y < secondText.frame.origin.y)
```